# On absolute values of sums and sub

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following definitions:

*(a)* $i$, $j$, $k$, and $l$ are all positive

*(b)*  $0< q < 1$

*(c)* $v=|i-k|$

*(d)* $w = |j-l|$

The problem is:

$x = |i- k + q(j-l)|$

Can i say anything about x in terms of v and w?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Look at the triangle inequality: $$ \left| x+y\right| \leq \left|x\right| + \left|y\right|$$
For any numbers $x$ and $y$.

So you can say, that $$ x = \left|i-k + q\cdot(j-l))\right| \overset{\triangle\text{-ineq.}}{\leq} \left|i-k\right| + \left|q\cdot (j-l)\right|$$
And, because $q$ is positive and less than $1$, you can further say, that
$$ \left|i-k\right| + \left|q\cdot (j-l)\right| \overset{\text{(b)}}{=} \left|i-k\right| + q\cdot\left|j-l\right| \overset{\text{(b)}}{<} \left|i-k\right| + \left|j-l\right| \overset{\text{(c) and (d)}}{=} v+w$$
So altogether, you get
$$ x < v+w $$
You actually don't need (a) anywhere.

Comment: @Paulo you are new here - did you know you could upvote the answers you are given by people, and also eventually accept them?